# R zip multiple files from multiple subfolers into one zip with one folder

Tags: r, zip

I have some files in some folders/subfolders

- subfolder1/file1.csv
- subfolder2/file2.csv

when using r to zip these files, with the following code

```
zip::zip("test.zip",files=c("subfolder1/file1.csv","subfolder2/file2.csv"))
```

It will create a zip file, but the files will be in their subfolders.

How can I create a zip file without the structure of the subfolders? which means that the files will be in the test.zip directly.

Comment: Not tested. But I would try with `zip(..., include_directories = FALSE)`

Comment: thank your stefan, often I forget to look at the arguments of the function. Your comment recall me to try with the various arguments. And actually the argument is `mode="cherry-pick"`), and intuitively, I would have said `include_directories` as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stefan's comment, I tried some arguments in the `zip::zip` function and found out the argument to do so:

```
zip(..., mode="cherry-pick")
```